# how to fetch data then update each item and save it

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This question relates to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116980/sort-filter-nsfetchrequest-how-to-write-sort-descriptor-taht-will-use-current-da). What is correct way to do:

1. fetch all data first time after app is opened
2. run through results and update some values
3. save updates

then when the appropriate/main fetch will occur to fill table it will contain updated data.

**UPDATE**

This fetch is NOT TO BE DISPLAYED in table but to update values that depends from current date. In other words I want to fetch data from Core Data only to perform update on one of attributes that depends on current date then save it back to CD. This updated values are then used in sorted fetch which is then used to fill table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you have to do is to `executeFetch` and operate on fatched data e.g form `NSArray`. You could do this in your main `NSManagedObjectContext` or create a new one. `NSManagedObjectContext` is like a draft... You can do there whatever you like. After you finish, just save it.

---

Okey, one more time. I guess you have something stored in `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, right? If so you have `NSManagedObjectContext` which is your **draft**. You create `NSEntityDescription` and do anything with these. After you've done with modifying you've everything inside your **MOC** and you have to save it or sync it with existing ones...

If it's not what you mean please explain it more deeply.

Comment: Please look at the question I'm referring there is code, I'm doing this but it seems not to store it back to Core Data. It means that property I'm updating for table use displays as updated (cell is using this value) but sort doesnt shows that it was modified, and values are not changed in the sqlite database. Would you be able to write some code to describe your solution?

Comment: I accept it as it is correct, my problems were from synthesising the property instead of leaving it `@dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but you can update specific rows or sections in a uitableview using the two methods below

[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)]
    [tableview reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)]

Comment: I know how to update table:) but the problem is that I need to perform update on information in Core Data so next fetch used in table will contain updated values.